# Keyboard stops working after source switch

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ibus

From time to time keyboard stops working after I switch source (i.e. using `ctrl + shift` combination). Most often it happens in Chrome yet I've experienced this in PyCharm IDE as well and maybe some other applications.
I should probably note, that keyboard stops working only in the application in which this problem triggered - if that happened in Chrome for example, I can't type there and all is fine with other apps.

I'm not **perfectly** sure that the source switching triggers it, yet it appears so.

What would you recommend me to do? 
If there's no obvious solution, how should I 'debug' it?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.10 (with Unity).

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I must also note that things were the same with `alt + shift` combination.

**UPDATE 2:** I followed advice by @ElderGeek and changed the source switching key to `f2`, for some time things were working well for me, but now the trouble is back. I need to relaunch an application in order to get keyboard working in it.

**UPDATE 3:** I confirm that keyboard turning off is not related to the source switching.

**UPDATE 4:** The problem persists after clean installation.

Comment: I'm not certain this is related, but please [edit] your question and include the application that you need to relaunch in order to get the keyboard working in it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you move the offending system to a different port on your KVM? Since my answer appears to have worked for over a week I have to consider intermittent hardware failure as a probable root cause.

Comment: The applications in which the keyboard had turned off occasionally are Chrome\Chromium, java-written IDE's from JetBrains, Nautilus.

I've never had done anything with KVM so I would need help with this part. What is "offending system" in this case?

Comment: Just something that pops into my mind, but could you try (temporarily) renaming `~/.config/dconf/`, log out and back in? It makes me think of a (possibly) corrupted `dconf` database like here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/599675/suddenly-cannot-switch-keyboard-layouts/600869#600869

Comment: I'm clearly barking up the wrong tree here due to a misunderstanding of the question. (A KVM is a hardware switch used to switch between computer systems using the same keyboard, mouse and monitor)

Comment: Just curious, but did you try renaming `~/.config/dconf/`, log out and back in?

Comment: Yes I did it few days ago and things are going well since then.
But that was also the case with the Elder Geek's advice, so can't be sure.

Please post your suggestion as an answer and I'll open a new bounty and award you with it if everything is ok within some more days later.

Comment: ...and so I did, posted it as an anwer :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem with Pycharm when I first installed **[Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/)** and did some customs, am still not sure if the problem occurred from **[Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/)**

Here is what you want to do:

1. Install  [DConf Editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/) & Lunch it.
2. Go to Desktop Then ibus
3. General
4. Now check the box next to use-global-engine and
   use-system-keyboard-layout

[image]

Edit: Make sure to match the keyboard input method:

1. System Settings > Language Support
2. At the bottom part find "Keyboard input method system"
3. Choose iBus, Or you can try all of them. (Required reboot)
4. After making the change, you need to restart for the settings to
   take effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of chrome specific keyboard shortcuts many of which use some combintaion of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This could easily create some incompatibilites with your "source switching" key combination.

Recommendation: Change your source switching key combo if possible to something not reserved for your commonly used applications.

Source: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Chrome.html

Comment: It was the same with "alt+shift". 
Still will try to change it to something else and see.

Comment: Can you change it to a function key other than F1?

Comment: I can. I will check the behaviour and comment later, because this happens occasionally.

Comment: Well, so far so good. I'm still not convinced that the trouble had gone, but no occurences still.

Comment: Sadly, the problem is still here.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be caused by a corrupted `dconf` database.

You can find out by removing or (temporarily?) renaming the directory `~/.config/dconf/`, and log out and back in to force the creation of a new database.

If it turns out to be the cause, you can remove the outdated database.

***Edit***
You mentioned in a comment that it has occurred on several installations already, and also after a clean install. That makes it almost certainly a hardware issue. That would also explain the unpredictable occurrence of the symptoms.

Comment: I should mention that the trouble started straight from the clean installation of Ubuntu (had this keyboard issue after several installations really), could the `dconf` database be corrupted at that point, prior to any of my actions that could've broken it?

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich Ah, I didn't know that. It seems unlikely, and if the issue already existed in previous installations, it seems more like a hardware issue.

Comment: If this occurs in every new installation of course it have to be hardware problem. Maybe you want to try different OS or keyboard and just try to go from there.

Comment: Baron, true, I didn't have this problem with OpenSUSE and I think with other flavors of Ubuntu too (non-Unity ones). I feel really dumb for not mentioning it from the beginning and wasting your time guys, thank you for your attention to the question.

Comment: One offtopic question, the bounty expires today, should I award it to someone or would it be against the ethics of this site to do this since no "real" solution was found?

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich I think no one can decide for you. If you don't award the bounty, half of it is awarded to the 2-up answer if I remember well. See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3579/should-i-feel-bad-about-not-giving-a-bounty-to-an-answer-on-a-bountied-question