# Suddenly cannot switch keyboard layouts

Tags: unity, keyboard, indicator, dconf

All of a sudden the keyboard layout icon disappeared from my bar, and even the keyboard short-cut that I usually use to switch between german and russian layout stopped working.

The "Text Entry" settings screen is now also completely unusable - none of the UI elements work there. The "input sources to use:" list is also empty, with no way to add or remove elements. Other UI elements on that settings screen even cannot be switched.

I don't remember doing anything that would require root privileges, besides updating my system, in the past couple of days. I didn't have this problem then.

I have Ubuntu 14.04. If you need further specs, write in the comments

Comment: I am not sure I understand all items you mention, but the icon should be visible with the command: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible true` does that change anything? If not, what is the output of the command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm the first command outputs an error:  
pavel@pavel-SATELLITE:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible true  

(process:9568): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code21: Cannot open dconf database: Failed to open file '/home/pavel/.config/dconf/user': Input/output error

Comment: second command outputs @a(ss) []

Comment: I don't have a solution, but that might be useful information to someone else.

Comment: Perfect! glad it worked. Would you mind if I posted it as an answer? (I removed the comment mentioning the link in your edit).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby you're too kind... , and you're right, it should have an answer. I am often restraint to post an answer if I have the feeling it will dye a lonely death, unnoticed and neglected by OP. Posted my answer, as it was made in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Normally*

You should be able to show/hide the icon using the commands: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible true` and `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false`

*However*

When you ran on my request the command(s) above, the output was:

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible true (process:9568): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code21: Cannot open dconf database: Failed to open file '/home/pavel/.config/dconf/user': Input/output error`

*The fix*

Googling around, I found [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165485), mentioning that your `dconf` database was probably corrupted.

As the link mentions, it can be solved by removing (alternatively: renaming) the database with the command:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak
```

Comment: @Fabby the question was answered in comments 3 days before this answer was written, so why should i return here? Don't be so salty.

Comment: @PavelBeliy I am pretty sure Fabby does not mean anything personal. What Fabby describes simply happens *a lot*. Just look through the database; a lot of excellent answers stay unaccepted, although highly upvoted. Indeed many "passing by" visitors just neglect the site and their own question after they got an anwer.  Sometimes hard to see if that is the case. Not so much a problem, but it is nicer if people take care of their question afterwards. Which you just did :)