# How to update iBus?

Tags: keyboard, ibus

I'm using PyCharm and sometimes the keyboard stops working because of [iBus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597189/keyboard-stops-working-after-source-switch/605224?s=1%7C0.1438#605224). The latest versions of PyCharm have a warning message recommending use of iBus 1.5.11 or newer.

1) How can I check the version of iBus?

2) How can I update iBus?

3) Can I safely remove iBus if I write in Dutch, Spanish and English (sometimes German)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1) Checking the version of IBus is simple

`ibus version`

2) Instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/735381)

Download the following files in a folder

[gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/wayland/+build/8264511/+files/gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11%2Bgit20151104-2-0ubuntu1%7Exenial1_amd64.deb)
[ibus_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/224259027/ibus_1.5.11%2Bgit20151104-2-0ubuntu1%7Exenial1_amd64.deb)
[ibus-gtk_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/224259025/ibus-gtk_1.5.11%2Bgit20151104-2-0ubuntu1%7Exenial1_amd64.deb)
[ibus-gtk3_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/224259024/ibus-gtk3_1.5.11%2Bgit20151104-2-0ubuntu1%7Exenial1_amd64.deb)
[libibus-1.0-5_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/224259028/libibus-1.0-5_1.5.11%2Bgit20151104-2-0ubuntu1%7Exenial1_amd64.deb)

Install

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Don't pay attention to the warnings and restart

3) No. `sudo apt-get remove ibus` gives the following warning:

> The following packages will be REMOVED
>   ibus ibus-table ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon

It seems like **ubuntu-desktop**, **unity-control-center** and **unity-control-center-signon** are important programs.

Comment: "Don't pay attention to the warnings" what kind of warnings are expected?